# How to plot weights of fully connected layer?

Tags: tensorflow, matplotlib

I am using a a fully connected network with 4 input and 2 output nodes. I store the Weights of my network after completely training it. Suppose here is my weight matrix

```
`W = np.array([[0.8,0.02],[0.5,0.4],[0.3,0.2],[0.1,0.7]])`
```

I want to visualize that what weights each class has adopted. How I can do that? I searched the codes related to this they are are using plt.imshow. Should I simply mention plt.imshow(W) to visualize weights?

Comment: Why don't you try `plt.imshow` and see if it's what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You should use TensorBoard for this. Also, you should not need to store the weights manually, as they are stored by TensorFlow. You can access them in a couple of different ways, such as with `tf.trainable_variables()`, or `tape.watched_variables()` in eager mode. Then its just a matter of looping through the variables for the weights you want.

To plot your weights in TensorBoard, check out this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/summary

Comment: Thanks. I didn't store the weights manually. I simply give a command W.eval() outside training loop to print weights. Is it correct way

Comment: Is there any other way than tensorboard? I want to use numpy and matplot to visualize because I am familiar with these

Comment: Personally, I would recommend taking the time to learn TensorBoard, as it is worth the time investment. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4) is a short video showing how to use it. If you are adamant to sticking with numpy and matplot though, you can of course use them. However, I am not very familiar with matplot so I can't be of much help there. Just make sure you use a global step to track the weight change over time.